# Form.Field components go out of bounds

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to make a Form which has a Form.Group inside, composed by 6 Form.Field's. This Form is located within a grid of 14 centered columns, having the equivalent of 2 columns as horizontal margins on each side (see the code bellow).

My problem is that the fields go out of bounds, breaking the margins. I'd like to have them all in one line, inside those 14 centered columns.

[image: Fields going out of bounds]

[image: Area for the Form and the horizontal margins]

Here is a sample of my code, showing the main components. The rest of the Form.Field's are basically the same with minimal changes.

```
return(
    ...
    <Grid centered={true}>
        <Grid.Column width={14}>
            <h2 style={{ marginBottom: '25px' }}>Edición de ficha</h2>
            <Form id="formulario">
                ...
                <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Field>
                            <label>
                                Admones. públicas u<br />
                                órganos competentes
                            </label>
                            <Select
                                name="publicAdm"
                                options={destAdmonesPub}
                                multiple={true}
                                value={selectedPublicAdm}
                                onChange={this.onChangePublicAdm}
                                />
                        </Form.Field>
                        ...
                    ...
                </Form.Group>
                ...
            </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something else going on with the CSS on your page than you have shared here. [I put together a codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-equal-width-form-row-wlv35?file=/example.js) to verify using the same props and components, multiple Form.Field will not break out of a Form.Group.

I suspect the issue is that there is CSS somewhere that is specifying a width or min-width to the Form.Field components which is causing them to break out of the row container.